# Homogeneous transport PDE with data along $t=0$ and $x=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics, transport-equation

I am finding an analytic expression for the solution of the transport PDE:
$$u_t+\left(\frac{1-2u(x,t)}{a}\right)u_x = 0,\quad a= \text{const.}, \quad x>0, \quad t >0$$
$$u(x=0,t) = u_0, \quad  u_0 = \text{const.} \in (0,1)$$
$$u(x,t=0) = \varphi(x)$$

I have got the solution:

$$
u(x,t) = \varphi\left(x-\frac{1-2u(x,t)}{a}\right)
$$

My question is how to use boundary condition $u_0$? I have checked many different books and articles, but  stuck though.

Thank you.

Comment: What $u_0 \in (0,1) - const$ means ? What is $u_0$ ? a given function of $t$ or a constant ?

Comment: @JJacquelin $u_0$ is a constant - any number between $0$ and $1$, for example $0.3$.

Comment: Meanwhile EditPiaf well answered to the question. I have nothing to add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct. The characteristic curves starting from $(x,t) = (x_0, 0)$ are the lines $x = x_0 + (1-2u)t/a$ along which $$u=\varphi(x_0) = \varphi\!\left(x - \frac{1-2u}{a}t\right)$$ is constant. In particular, the line starting from $x_0 = 0^+$ satisfies $x = (1-2\varphi(0))t/a$. Note that the implicit expression above is only valid up to the breaking time.

For the other part, characteristic curves starting from $(x,t) = (0, t_0)$ are the lines $t = t_0 + ax/(1-2u)$ along which $u = u_0$ is constant. In particular, the line starting from $t_0 = 0^+$ satisfies $t = ax/(1-2u_0)$. Now, it remains to analyze the interaction of both parts... Do these curves intersect, or do they separate? What if $\varphi(0)=u_0$? (Hint: sketch the characteristics in the $x$-$t$ plane)

Comment: I would assume that for $t = \frac{ax}{1-2u_0}$ the value $u_0$ is in between $0$ and $0.5$ as $x >0$ and $t >0$. Same for $x = \frac{1-2\varphi(0)}{a}t$ for which $\varphi(0) \in [0,0.5] $. I am not sure if it helps in the analysis.

Comment: @Alando Personally, I would try the cases $u_0 \in [0,\frac12[$ and $u_0 \in ]\frac12,1]$ separately.